# Does an onboarding/warm welcome screen affect Firebase app indexing content mismatch

Tags: android, firebase-app-indexing

Following the material design guidelines, our app has an onboarding/warm welcome screen when the user first launches it: https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/onboarding.html#. When implementing Firebase app indexing, our app handles both the home URL and deeplink URLs, such as:

- /
- /some-deep-link

But with the Fetch as Google tool, I see the warm welcome screen displayed when both these URLs are tested. Will this affect Google's content mismatch test documented at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6216428?#content_mismatch ? If so, what is the workaround, given that the warm welcome/onboarding screen is an official Android Material design pattern?

Regards,
ak